# How to Call a function present in custom adapter class from other activity class?

Tags: android

This is my CustomAdapter Class Where I have a function call setFilter

```
package Adapter;

public class CustomAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
private Context c;
private List list;


public CustomAdapter(Context context, List itemlist) {
    this.c= context;
    this.list=itemlist;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup 
parent, int viewType) {

View  view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,parent,false
    );
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int 
position) {
    Contact_Object listItem = (Contact_Object) list.get(position);
 holder.text1.setText(listItem.getName());
 holder.text2.setText(listItem.getNumber());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener{
     TextView text1,text2;
    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
       text1=view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
       text2=view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    }

    public  void  setFilter(List<Contact_Object> listItem){
          list=new ArrayList<>();
          list.addAll(listItem);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position=getAdapterPosition();
        Contact_Object item= (Contact_Object) list.get(position);
        Intent intent=new Intent(c, ContactDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("name",item.getName());
        intent.putExtra("number",item.getNumber());
        c.startActivity(intent);
      }
   }
  }
```

This is MainActivity Class from where I want to call the setFilter function I am using searchView setOnQueryListener when user search I want to show the found list as a drop-down list

```
    this is how I have setup my showContact function and adapter object of 
    CustomAdapter class 



   void showContacts() {
    // Check the SDK version and whether the permission is already granted 
   or not.
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && 
   checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != 
   PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) != 
   PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        for (String permission : PERMISSIONS) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {// Android version is lesser than 6.0 or the permission is already 
    granted.
        ArrayList<Contact_Object> contacts=getContactNames();
        adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,contacts);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
  }


  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if (!searchView.isIconified()){
                searchView.setIconified(true);
                }
            myMenuItem.collapseActionView();
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            final List<Contact_Object> filtermodelist=filter(list,newText);
           //here i am calling like adapter.setFilter(filterlist);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but adapter.setFilter()  is showing error ;
Please anyone help me out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method

```
 public  void  setFilter(List<Contact_Object> listItem){
      list=new ArrayList<>();
      list.addAll(listItem);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

seems to in ViewHolder class which is not accessible from out side of class move this setFilter method outside of ViewHolder class

Comment: Okay  Let me see